# Polar to Cartesian conversion on location change

Tags: ios, geospatial, computational-geometry, unity-game-engine

I've been searching SO and Unity Answers for weeks now and been unable to solve this problem.  I have a 3d object in Unity that is instantiated based on the user's current lat/long (let's say 41.23423, -122.87978) then i want to move the object to the new lat/long whenever their location changes.

So 41.23423, -122,87978 becomes 0,0,0 in my 3D environment and i apply changes relative to that original location.

I am coding in C# and when the action fires for a location change, i compare the two lat/longs and calculate distance and angle then do a polar to cartesian conversion and move the object to the new location.

My problem is that the updates are moving the object, but produce some erratic results, which i'm guessing is a problem in my code.  For example, if i toggle between two locations, the first change will move to (131.6, 0.0, 0.0) but then toggling it back moves doesn't move the object.  Or i've also seen in testing occasions where the first change will yield an unexpected coordinate, but any subsequent changes (toggling between two points) yields the same relative values for each location.

I don't have a good handle on what i'm doing wrong here, so any help would be greatly appreciated, and apologies in advance if this question is too vague or a duplicate question (either problems in my code or perhaps i'm not approaching the problem correctly)

Here's the code for my class that moves the object based on location.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class CameraMover : MonoBehaviour {
const double PIx = 3.141592653589793;
const double RADIO = 20925721.8;
public CoreLocationData lastLocationData;
public int firstUpdate = 0;
private Vector3 currentVector;
private Vector3 newVector;
// Use this for initialization
void OnEnable () {
CoreLocationManager.locationServicesDidUpdate += locationServicesDidUpdate;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void locationServicesDidUpdate( CoreLocationData locationData )
{
    if (firstUpdate == 0)
    lastLocationData = locationData;

    double newDistance = DistanceBetweenPlaces(lastLocationData.longitude, lastLocationData.latitude, locationData.longitude, locationData.latitude);
    double angleToMove = Angle(lastLocationData.latitude, lastLocationData.longitude, locationData.latitude, locationData.longitude);

    double newX = (newDistance * Math.Cos(angleToMove));
    double newZ = (newDistance * Math.Sin(angleToMove));
    float newXfloat = System.Convert.ToSingle(newX);
    float newZfloat = System.Convert.ToSingle(newZ);

    currentVector = this.gameObject.transform.position;
    newVector = new Vector3(newXfloat, 0.0F, newZfloat);
    this.gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentVector, newVector, 1);

    Debug.Log(string.Format("Distance To Move is {0}, angle is {1}", newDistance, angleToMove));
    Debug.Log(string.Format("Moving from {0} to {1}", currentVector, newVector));
    lastLocationData = locationData;

    firstUpdate = 1;

}

public static double Radians(double x)
{
    return x * PIx / 180;
}

public static double DistanceBetweenPlaces(
    double lon1,
    double lat1,
    double lon2,
    double lat2)
{
    double dlon = Radians(lon2 - lon1);
    double dlat = Radians(lat2 - lat1);

    double a = (Math.Sin(dlat / 2) * Math.Sin(dlat / 2)) + Math.Cos(Radians(lat1)) * Math.Cos(Radians(lat2)) * (Math.Sin(dlon / 2) * Math.Sin(dlon / 2));
    double angle = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a));
    return angle * RADIO;
}


public double Angle(double px1, double py1, double px2, double py2)
{
// Negate X and Y values
double pxRes = px2 - px1;
double pyRes = py2 - py1;
double angle = 0.0;
// Calculate the angle
if (pxRes == 0.0)
{
   if (pxRes == 0.0)
         angle = 0.0;
   else if (pyRes > 0.0)          angle = System.Math.PI / 2.0;
   else
         angle = System.Math.PI * 3.0 / 2.0;
}
else if (pyRes == 0.0)
{
   if (pxRes > 0.0)
         angle = 0.0;
   else
         angle = System.Math.PI;
}
else
{
   if (pxRes < 0.0)
         angle = System.Math.Atan(pyRes / pxRes) + System.Math.PI;
   else if (pyRes < 0.0)          angle = System.Math.Atan(pyRes / pxRes) + (2 * System.Math.PI);
   else
         angle = System.Math.Atan(pyRes / pxRes);
}
// Convert to degrees
angle = angle * 180 / System.Math.PI;return angle;

}
}
```

**EDIT**

Correct Implementation:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class CameraMover : MonoBehaviour
{
  const double RATIO = 20902231.0029;
  public CoreLocationData lastLocationData;
  public int firstUpdate = 0;
  private Vector3 currentVector;
  private Vector3 newVector;

  // Use this for initialization
  void OnEnable ()
  {
    CoreLocationManager.locationServicesDidUpdate += locationServicesDidUpdate;
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () { }

  public void locationServicesDidUpdate( CoreLocationData locationData )
  {
    if (firstUpdate == 0)
    {
      lastLocationData = locationData;
    }

    double newDistance = DistanceBetweenPlaces(lastLocationData.longitude, lastLocationData.latitude, locationData.longitude, locationData.latitude);
    double angleToMove = AngleBetweenPlaces(lastLocationData.latitude, lastLocationData.longitude, locationData.latitude, locationData.longitude);
    double angleToMoveRadians = Deg2Rad(angleToMove);
    double newX = (newDistance * Math.Sin(angleToMoveRadians));
    double newZ = (newDistance * Math.Cos(angleToMoveRadians));
    float newXfloat = System.Convert.ToSingle(newX) * -1;
    float newZfloat = System.Convert.ToSingle(newZ) * -1;

    Debug.Log(string.Format("new x coordinate should be {0} and z should be {1}", newXfloat, newZfloat));

    currentVector = this.gameObject.transform.position;
    this.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3((currentVector.x + newXfloat),0, (currentVector.z + newZfloat));
    lastLocationData = locationData;
    firstUpdate = 1;
  }

  public static double DistanceBetweenPlaces(
    double lon1,
    double lat1,
    double lon2,
    double lat2)
  {
    double phi1 = Deg2Rad(lat1);
    double phi2 = Deg2Rad(lat2);
    double deltaLamdba = Deg2Rad(lon2 - lon1);
    double d = Math.Acos(
      (Math.Sin(phi1) * Math.Sin(phi2)) + 
      (Math.Cos(phi1) * Math.Cos(phi2) * Math.Cos(deltaLamdba)));

    return d * RATIO;
  }

  public static double Deg2Rad(double degrees)
  {
    return degrees * (Math.PI / 180.0);
  }

  public static double Rad2Deg(double radians)
  {
    return radians * (180.0 / Math.PI);
  }

  public double AngleBetweenPlaces(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
  {
    var newLat1 = Deg2Rad(lat1);
    var newLat2 = Deg2Rad(lat2);
    var dLon = Deg2Rad(lon2) - Deg2Rad(lon1);
    var y = Math.Sin(dLon) * Math.Cos(newLat2);
    var x = Math.Cos(newLat1) * Math.Sin(newLat2) - Math.Sin(newLat1) * Math.Cos(newLat2) * Math.Cos(dLon);
    var brng = Math.Atan2(y, x);
    return (Rad2Deg(brng) + 360) % 360;
  }
}
```

Comment: I probably don't have the trig knowledge to debug your code, but I may be able to find another solution.

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the problem, however. This is my interpretation of your problem: You wish to instantiate an object that will keep the same relative position to the player on a globe.

Is this correct?

Comment: Basically the problem is i'm downloading markers from my server that are essentially geo-cached data (pictures, messages, etc) and these objects all have a static lat/long.  I'm placing the user at 0,0 and then as the user's location changes i need to move the user while keeping the other objects at proper relative distances to the user (e.g. user is instantiated at 0,0 with an object at 10,0 then user moves to the lat/long equivalent of 5,0 and the object at 10,0 is now 5 units away form the user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some points you are using `System.Math.PI` and at others you are using `PIx = 3.141592653589793` - what is the reason for this? Also, what is `RADIO`, from its use I would presume it to be a mean radius of the earth in Km, but the value is waaay out.

Also the `DistanceBetweenPlaces` method has a couple of errors, anyhow, try the following, if you have problems with the accuracy then I would use [Vincenty's formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae), otherwise stick with simple spherical law of cosines.

```
// Earths Mean Radius in Kilometres?
public const double RADIO = 6371;

public static double DistanceBetweenPlaces(
    double lon1,
    double lat1,
    double lon2,
    double lat2)
{
  double phi1 = Deg2Rad(lat1);
  double phi2 = Deg2Rad(lat2);
  double deltaLamdba = ConvertDegreesToRadians(lon2 - lon1);
  double d = Math.Acos((Math.Sin(phi1) * Math.Sin(phi2)) + (Math.Cos(phi1) * Math.Cos(phi2) * Math.Cos(deltaLamdba)));
  return d * RADIO;

}

public static double Deg2Rad(double degrees)
{
    return degrees == 0 ? degrees : (degrees * Math.PI / 180.0);
}
```

Also, check this great resource for working with geodesic data

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Fraser, thanks for this.  I will try it today and report back.  I'm not sure why i was using PIx and Math.PI, but the two are interchangeable, i think i had just borrowed the convert to radians method which referenced the PIx constant variable and hadn't updated it to use Math.PI yet.  the RADIO variable is the earth's radius, but in feet, since feet is the unit of measurement i'm using for my x,y,z coordinates in 3d space

Comment: If it where feet it would be 20902231 not 20925721.8  Also, take a look at this blog, gives a great implementation of the vincenty I mentioned - http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/free-source-code/geodesy-library-vincentys-formula/ - and this page has every calc I think you would need (in javascipt, easy to translate)  http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Thank you so much.  I implemented your methods and fixed my constants and my log began reporting the correct distance and angle, but then jumping between two locations always yielded a remainder: i would start at 0,0 go to the new location at 123,12 then come back to the original location and it would be at 77,-35 instead of 0,0.  This, as it turns out was because i was not converting back to degrees (doh!).  Correct code now inserted in post for others trying to do this.  Thanks again, i had feared getting flamed when posting on SO for a long time, but my first experience was great

Comment: No worries, glad to have helped